# Move position of the plotly modebar from right to left in R

Tags: r, plotly

I want to move the position of the plotly modebar from top right to top left in a plotly plot, using R.  ([This is the modebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpB4t.png))

I think I should be able to adjust this in R using:

```
ggplotly(example) %>% config(config_parametr = XYZ)
```

But I can’t find what config_parameter controls the position of the modebar. Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: Any luck working this out?   I'm stuck in the same place with the modebar overlapping my figure title.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: \still no solution? I would like to habe it centered